# drupal---comment reply

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

now i want to make the comment "reply" to this style [reply], how to do that? namely, add the square bracket to the reply text.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the button text?  If so, you can use a [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) and change the value of the button:

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_if == 'your_form_id'{ 
    $form['buttons']['reply']['#value'] = t('[reply]');
  }
}
```

You need to look at your form to see exactly where the reply button is located.

Answer (score 0):

if you're uncomfortable using hook_form_alter, you can also use the String Overrides module, to replace any text that passes through the t() function.

http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides